# Does the Devourer target itself with soul rend?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, actions

The Devourer monster from Monsters of the Multiverse has an ability called Soul Rend. The abilities does the following:

> Soul Rend (Recharge 6). The devourer creates a vortex of life-draining energy in a 20-foot radius centered on itself. Each creature in that area must make a DC 18 Constitution saving throw, taking 44 (8d10) necrotic damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

Based on the wording, the ability seems to target the devourer itself, but I'm uncertain because of the use of the word vortex in there. Does it target itself or not?

Comment: Without a context of why it matters if it targets itself or not, I don’t think we can really give a meaningful answer here. For what purpose do you want to know if it targets itself? Because the wording of the particular feature it might be interesting with matters for how we should read this one.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I suppose the question is about whether Soul Rend damages the Devourer itself (forces it to do the CON save)

Comment: @justhalf Ah, good thinking, that does make sense. Edoreld, just to confirm, you’re asking if the devourer’s soul rend damages itself?

Comment: This issue has come up before in one of my games (as a player) with [Vampiric Mind Flayer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/1680955-vampiric-mind-flayer)'s Disrupt Psyche ability, which area is also a sphere centered on self, but doesn't mention anything against itself being unaffected. The DM was both generous to also make it affect the mind flayer itself when another player pointed that out, and also salty that the RAW is unusable. Haha

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### As written it does, but that is probably an error

#### The MP:MoM version both targets and damages itself

As you correctly cite,

> The devourer creates a vortex of life-draining energy in a 20-foot radius centered on itself. Each creature in that area must make a DC 18 Constitution saving throw, taking 44 (8d10) necrotic damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

The effect is **centered on itself**, which includes itself.  "**Each creature** in that area" includes itself, since it is a creature.  The Devourer is not immune to necrotic damage (it is immune to poison).

#### The VGM version did not

An earlier version of the Devourer appeared in *Volo's Guide to Monsters*.  The *Soul Rend* ability there had one crucial difference: it said "Each **humanoid** in that area must make..."  Since the Devourer is a fiend, not a humanoid, the VGM version neither targeted nor damaged itself.

This specific targeting of humanoids has less to do with excluding itself (as @Philipp points out, it not only excludes the Devourer, but also animal companions, summons, wild-shaped druids, *etc*.) and more to do with the dramatic context of the demon.  The lore, in both versions, says that Orcus created these demons specifically to "hunt humanoids, with the intent of consuming them body and soul."  In both versions, humanoids are the target of its *Imprison Soul* ability, which then creates undead from the victims (and note that the *animate dead* spell targets only humanoids).

It seems like a strange change to make the ability both target and damage the Devourer.  Since it still travels with the packs of undead that it creates, none of which are immune to necrotic, they would be affected as well by such a change.  It was likely an editorial error in updating the monsters to the new format of *MP:MoM*.

Comment: @Philipp Thank you.  Please see update.